# Downloading videos and storing them locally swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, video, download

Could someone please provide from their experience the step-by-step guide or some tips how to download the videos from some specific url, save it locally (please suggest which database to use CoreData, realm or SQLite) and then show it to the user for example in the collectionView?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, do not store the videos in a database. Use the [documents directory](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html). For downloading the videos you can use the `URLSession`’s `dataTask(with:completionHandler:)` method or a library such as Alamofire. Once downloaded to local storage, you can go through the files stored there and filter them by extension if you have more file types than just videos. This can be done asynchronously in `viewDidLoad()`, storing the URLs into an array, then bind them to your collection and call `reloadData()`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.